# jquery-oembed-all append iframe to a div makes page too slow to render

Tags: jquery, iframe, oembed

I'm using a plugin jquery-oembed-all. Plugin provides oembed featues to dynamically embed external urls into the site.

Plugin does all the heavy lifting of resolving oembed content and then does the following:

```
oembedContainer.append(oembedData.code);
```

> Where **oembedContainer** is a dynamically generated span on local page that will hold the
>   embeded fetched contents and  **oembedData.code** are the actual contents
>   fetched.

oembedData.code could be an iframe too which is the usual case for youtube and other video contents.

If I have many videos on the same page, now each iframe takes hell lot of time to load and my page busy indiciator never stops. I find it difficult to scroll the page as well unless all the iframes are fully loaded.

I wonder how facebook provides such a smooth UI (yeah, they're facebook.)

Any suggestions, how can I improve this situation?

Comment: Hi I'm the author of that plugin.
How many item are you loading? Is it just IFrames that are slow or do the embeds work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at the code to see why it is slow.

Youtube does not supply a JSONP option for oembed ([see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/5KuXxlLK07g)), meaning that the library can't get the oembed over a browser directly. To get around this Yahoo YQL is used to get the OEmbed data and wrap it in some JSONP. YQL takes some time to return data (1-2 seconds I find) so  with lots of requests it will take a long time.

There are 2 options for this:
1. get Youtube to add JSONP to it's oembed - not likely as it was asked for and they have said that since it is not part of the official spec they wont support it. 
2. Change the library to go back to using iframe lookup :) - Far more likely - just add a ticket on github and I'll see what I can do.

Andrew

Comment: Could it not be possible to load iframes asynchronously and not append to main page body unless they're fully loaded? I can see the problem is with iframes only other embed just works fine. Not related to slow responses but also with youtube I can see unless you append wmode=transparent to the iframe src they return, youtube iframe doesn't honour the z-index of other components on the page. Is there any work around for that?

Comment: One more question. What's the best way to call oembed function? Should I call it for every item when rendered (passing in the id selector $('#somelinkid')). Or should I call it once after complete rendering of the page and call oembed on css selector $('.oembed')? Basically the page I am using this plugin upon is a facebook clone, and it's a users social feed, so there could be 100s of posts on the same page and also new posts could be coming in on various events.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty sure it does them in async atm. Not sure about appending them until they are fully loaded - I'll have to look into that. If I change it to an Iframe I can add the wmode perhaps.

Can you please make a ticket for these things on github as I will likely forget as I don't look at stack overflow often :)

I find that it's best load all at once via a selector and then as new items are loaded to then trigger just for these new items.